# Do I need to create database indexes of all possible combinations?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

I have an index in my database table:

```
[ArcadeID] ASC,
[Published] ASC,
[AccessMode] ASC,
[ContentTypeID] ASC,
[SupportedDeviceTypes] ASC,
[LanguageID] ASC
```

The last three columns `ContentTypeID`, `SupportedDeviceTypes` and `LanguageID` are all optional. This index is used when listing all games in an arcade when certain filters are applied.

If these columns are included/excluded in all the various combinations, to get maximum query performance would I need to create all possible combinations of this index or would the above index cover all combinations already?

Comment: This seems like it would be better asked on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Regardless of the location of where you ask this you need to provide some details. It is far too broad and vague as posted.

Comment: @SeanLange what details am I missing?  I want to know if I need to create more indexes for maximum query performance if the last three columns are optional?

Comment: We don't know what your queries look like. Any advice you receive with so little detail would be guessing. Keep in mind too that every index you create may help retrieving data but it will slow down inserts and updates. There just isn't a magical formula here that will work in every situation. Proper indexing is almost more art than science.

Comment: OK, is the question not clear enough regarding how the queries might look?  The first 3 columns are mandatory when fetching a list of games.  The last 3 columns are all optional depending on filters applied, meaning there are several combos of columns queried.  

I've also stated I'm after maximum query performance here, understand there are costs elsewhere.

Comment: If it's a specific query you're trying to tune, then we need to query itself, and the query plan (use Paste the Plan). if it's more general, then we need knowledge of *what* is often queried in your table, or frequent queries that are run. In both cases the full DDL of the table, with the current indexes, are a need. For the latter, the knowledge you have of your system is going to be difficult to convey easily; you know your system and it's uses far better than us, so therefore you'll *should* know what might be needed in an index.

Comment: `you should know what might be needed in an index` - I do, and I am wondering if I need to create indexes with all combinations of fields included/excluded.  Example if `SupportedDeviceTypes` is omitted, will the above index still be used by the DB, or would I need to create a new index with `SupportedDeviceTypes` not included?

Comment: IF the last three columns are optional filters in the query and can have different combinations in the order, you don't need to include them in the index. The index will still be used in most cases (depends on how selective it is) regardless what filters are used in your query because the query conditions with the first three columns are always there.

Comment: Other considerations: How many other columns you have in the table? Do you select all of them in this query?

Comment: It sounds like you have a covering index already, especially with the last three columns only sometimes being included. I would be reluctant to add more indexes unless there is a performance issue that you are running into.

Comment: @SeanLange great that's the answer I was looking for, if the index I posted covers the queries where the last few fields might be excluded.  Thank you.

Comment: @PeterHe lots of other columns but they are not queried.  Not sure why selection would be important for this question, but no only the PK is selected on this query.

Comment: @TomGullen If your query only select a few columns, you can add those columns in the INCLUDE clause.  CREATE INDEX idx_xxx ON table(ArcadeID] ASC,
[Published] ASC,
[AccessMode] ASC) INCLUDE (Other columns). THis will save the PRIMARY KEY lookup, which is expensive.  THis will make the index a covering index for your query.

Comment: @SeanLange The index actually is not a covering index unless all the columns being selected are either indexed columns or in the INCLUDE clause.

Comment: @PeterHe Sean knows what a covering index is.

Comment: @MJH with all the respect, my comments were based on the question and his comments.

Comment: @PeterHe no worries. I was making assumptions that the "optional" columns were not always returned. Perhaps it meant that sometimes they are part of the where predicates. Another shining example of why it would have been important for the OP to provide these details. Guessing at answers to partial questions is not easy. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an index is searched, it is traversed throught the first column of the key, then the second column etc.

You are saying that the first 3 columns are mandatory. If you search for exact matches, then you don't need different indexes for different order of these 3 columns. However, if you use wildcard searches (such as AccessMode LIKE '[RW]'), then it does matter.

For the optional columns, the order also matters, but only if by then (after pinpointing the exact ArcadeID, Published and AccessMode) the selection is still too large.

When you use exact match searches (as described above), the order of first 3 mandatory columns is best done based on the statistical properties. The most selective column should be listed first, then the next most selective column.